# May types be defined in `decltype` or `sizeof` expressions in C++20?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, decltype

Since C++20 lambda functions are allowed in unevaluated contexts, and in particular they should be allowed inside `decltype` and `sizeof` expressions.

In its turn, lambdas can define some types in their bodies and possible return objects of these types, for example:

```
using T = decltype( []{ struct S{}; return S{}; } );

[[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto N 
          = sizeof( []{ struct S{}; return S{}; } );
```

Clang accepts this code, but GCC emits the errors:

```
error: types may not be defined in 'decltype' expressions
    1 | using T = decltype( []{ struct S{}; return S{}; } );
error: types may not be defined in 'sizeof' expressions
    4 |           = sizeof( []{ struct S{}; return S{}; } );
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9aY1KWfbq

Which one of the compilers is right here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restrictions on lambdas in unevaluated contexts that were removed as of [P0315R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r4.pdf) means this is not prohibited (albeit a corner case), and thus arguably GCC has a bug here. Particularly the following discussion from the paper is relevant here:

> Furthermore, some questions were raised on the Core reflector
> regarding redeclarations like this:
>
> ```
> template <int N> static void k(decltype([]{ return 0; }()));
> template <int N> static void k(decltype([]{ return 0; }())); // okay
> template <int N> static void k(int); // okay
> ```
>
> These should be valid redeclarations, since the lambda expressions are
> evaluated, and they neither contain a template parameter in their body
> nor are part of a full-expression that contains one. Hence, the
> lambda-expression does not need to appear in the signature of the
> function, **and the behavior is equivalent to this, without requiring
> any special wording:**
>
> ```
> struct lambda { auto operator()() const { return 0; } };
> template <int N> static void k(decltype(lambda{}()));
> template <int N> static void k(decltype(lambda{}())); // okay today
> template <int N> static void k(int); // okay today
> ```

The same argument holds also for the OP's example, and (arguably) *"the behavior is equivalent to this, without requiring any special wording"*:

```
struct lambda { auto operator()() const { struct S{}; return S{}; } };
using T = decltype(lambda{});
```

---

> ```
> [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto N 
>           = sizeof( []{ struct S{}; return S{}; } );
> ```

Note that the `sizeof` is simpler, as you are querying the size of the captureless lambda's closure type, and not the size of the local struct `S`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted to call the lambda inside decltype/sizeof: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jYjxcr1eP But the result is the same as in the original question.

Comment: @Fedor I thought as much when I the ”equivalent example”. Afaict this is legal, and quite similar to the example quoted above (similarity to a simple functor class, where you naturally have no restrictions on local class definitions). I’d say this isa GCC bug.

Comment: Thanks. I have reported GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102367